# How to fix Undefined reference to in C++?

Tags: c++

So I'm a C++ newbie taking a MOOC on CS Fundamentals. I am trying to create a class to find the volume of a Cube. When I run the file I get "undefined reference to `Cube::getVolume()". I'm not sure why the function isn't being called right because I copied the text straight off the screen. I know I set my compiler up correctly because I was able to run the first module's information correctly.

'''

```
    #pragma once

    class Cube {
        public:
          double getVolume();
          double getSurfaceArea();
          void setLength(double length);

        private:
          double length_;
    };

    #include "Cube.h"
    {
    double Cube::getVolume() {
        return length_ * length_ * length_ ;
    }

    double Cube::getSurfaceArea() {
        return 6 * length_ * length_ ;
    }

    void Cube::setLength(double length) {
        length_ = length;
    }}
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Cube.h"

    int main() {
        Cube c;

        c.setLength(3.48);
        double volume = c.getVolume();
        std::cout << "Volume: " << volume << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the files `"Cube.h"`, `"Cube.cpp"` and `"main.cpp"` concatenated together. They are supposed to be separate.

Comment: Had to look up MOOC. Make sure it wasn't Master Of Orion 100. Last I saw was MOOIII, so I was pretty worried that I'd been blown out of my trajectory into an orbit which froze my life support and returned me to Earth five-hundred years later.

Comment: `{    double Cube::getVolume()` is a syntax error, the compiler should diagnose

Comment: It seems that your question gets misunderstood only because of its formatting problems. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and fix that problem.

Comment: Assuming that you did actually setup your environment correctly to build two code files and a header file, and that you only fumbled the formatting, try removing the pair of `{}` containing all of the first of the code files, i.e. the second file you have shown. (This is basically repeating the comment by @M.M , just with more details.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except formatting in the Cube.cpp (as mentioned above, you have unneeded curly braces). I guess that the problem is not in code but rather in your build/compilation commands. Which compiler and/or IDE do you use?

Here is an generic (Linux/macOS) command line example of how you can build your code:

`g++ main.cpp Cube.cpp -o CubeApp`

run your program:

`./CubeApp`

Cube.h

```
#pragma once

class Cube {
    public:
      double getVolume();
      double getSurfaceArea();
      void setLength(double length);

    private:
      double length_ = 0.0;
};
```

Cube.cpp

```
#include "Cube.h"


double Cube::getVolume() {
    return length_ * length_ * length_ ;
}

double Cube::getSurfaceArea() {
    return 6 * length_ * length_ ;
}

void Cube::setLength(double length) {
    length_ = length;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cube.h"

int main() {
    Cube c;

    c.setLength(3.48);
    double volume = c.getVolume();
    std::cout << "Volume: " << volume << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```